# Possible to read file from git cache?

Tags: git, git-ls-files

I can see list of files using below command

```
git ls-files --cache
```

Wondering if it's possible to read the content of the listed file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  [`git cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) or [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show). For example

```
for f in `git ls-files --cache`; do
    echo -- "----- File (cat): $f -----"
    git cat-file -p HEAD:$f
    echo -- "----- File (show): $f -----"
    git show HEAD:$f
    echo -- "----- End of File: $f -----"
done
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. If I run a command like `git show HEAD:yarn.lock`, then from where will it pick the content from? From `HEAD`? Or from `git cache`?

Comment: From the `HEAD`. Do you want index? (It's now called index, not cache). Just use `:$file`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [checkout-index](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/git-checkout-index.html). This command copies a file from the git cache (index) into the worktree.

Normally it overrides the working copy, but with the parameter `--temp` you could create a copy of your file.

```
git checkout-index --temp -- myfile.ext
```